# How to update foreign key from yii2-advanced curd

Tags: foreign-keys, yii2-advanced-app

I have created a curd using curd generation (with table `status`) in yii2-advanced application. and curd(create,view,edit,delete) is working properly.

Now I have created a new table `relation (id, user_id, status_id)` where `user_id` is the foreign key for `user` table and `status_id` is also foreign key for `status` table.

Now I want to update table `relation` on update `status` table.

**For example :**

1) If user `test` (user_id is 1) creates new `status` then there will be a new entry in `relation` table like `relation (1, 1, {status_id just created by user})` .

2) if user delete status then the row with this `status_id` will also be removed from `relation` table.

3) And these created status only visible to user_id 1 only not to other users.

I am new to this framework, so please guide me how to implement this scenario in my application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a before delete function to your model like this:

```
public function beforeDelete(){
        if ( $this->getRelations()->count()!=0){
        foreach($this->getRelations() as $relation)
        {
            if (Yii::$app->user->identity->id == $relation->user_id){
                $relation->delete(); 
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Also you can change AccessControl in your controller!